# How can i set root viewController of NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

i am using TabBar in my application i want to set viewController on tab clicked.
My tabs rootviewcontroller is NavigationController.i want to change root viewController of that tab's navigation controller eachTime new on tab select.

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())

let tab = UITabBarController()
tab.viewControllers = [nav1, nav2]

appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = tab
```

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?  In Xcode 7.2, the initializer for setting a root view controller on a `UINavigationController` is `rootViewController`: `UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())`